# does scala implicitly call some methods?

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a class that contains code that I can tell from the logs is definitively being executed, but I cannot figure out where the method is being called. I am wondering, if a class has a `get()` method defined, is it automatically called somehow, parhaps if other code in the class is executed? Is `get()` magic?

I cannot share my actual code for privacy reasons. The following is complete BS code, but I hope it is enough for people to see what I'm talking about.

If I look for usages in my IDE of the `A.get()` method, there are none. The only usage of the `A.getHistory()` method is inside the `A.get()` method. Finally, there are also usages of the `A.extra()` method.

```
class A(count: Int) {     
  def get (date: LocalDateTime) : List[B] = {
    getHistory(date, 0).get
  }

  def getHistory(date: LocalDateTime, tries: Int) : Try[List[B]] = Try({
    val b : B = new B (date)
    logger.info("method getHistory() is being called")
  }) match {
    case s: Success[List[B]] => s
    case e: Failure[List[UnitChange]] => 
      Thread.sleep(retryDelay)
      getHistory(date, tries + 1)   
  }

  def extra() = {
    logger.info("method extra() is being called")
  }
}

object C {
  def run() {
    A.extra()
  }
}
```

If `C.run()` calls `A.extra()`, does `A.get()` implicitly get called?

U: I have to support this code without being a real Scala developer. But I also need to know because I've been porting it to Java, and if methods are being magically called in Scala, that won't happen in Java, and I need to make some changes to make sure the magic code does get executed.

U: This is embarrassing, but it appears I diagnosed a zebra when it was a horse all the time. In other words ... it was a mistake on my part, the code in question was *not* getting called, and no magic is taking place.

Comment: You can try to delete this method, recompile the project and explore compilation errors.

Comment: interesting idea. the service listens to a message queue - if i can figure out how to kick off this functionality, i can put in breakpoints and trace progress through the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of one example of a `get()` call hidden inside of a pattern match. I rather doubt this is what you're seeing, but it's worth knowing about.

```
class MyClass(val arg: Int) {
  def get: String = "what it takes"
  def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
object MyClass {
  def unapply(mc: MyClass): MyClass = mc
}
new MyClass(42) match {
  case MyClass(x) => s"got $x"   //res0: String = got what it takes
  case _          => "not"
}
```

The `unapply()` gets called as part of the pattern match. `unapply()` usually returns an `Option` but it doesn't have to. Whatever it returns has to have an `isEmpty` and a `get`, both of which are called to complete the procedure.

Comment: Marking as the answer since you did try to address my question, which I've now edited to explain how it's fatally flawed. Thanks for trying!